# Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.intro; bundle-version="3.4.0"

Tags: eclipse, migration, eclipse-rcp, equinox

We are working on migrating Eclipse RCP project from Eclipse 4.6.3 to Eclipse 4.15.
We have all the jars in plugins folder from Eclipse 4.15.
When launch the code in Eclipse 4.15 product launches successfully.
But when we build in gradle and generate executable.
Getting exception like below.
I am getting lot of errors but,I have put one error.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.intro.quicklinks 4 0 2022-09-26 06:17:24.126
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.ui.intro.quicklinks [289]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.intro; bundle-version="3.4.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.intro; bundle-version="3.5.900.v20200217-1223"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.intro [286]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.6.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.116.0.v20200203-1308"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.ui [276]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.117.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.118.1.v20220104-1840"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.ui.workbench [309]
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands
                         -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"; bundle-version="0.12.900.v20200110-1732"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,  org.eclipse.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress,  org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.tests"
                            org.eclipse.e4.core.commands [92]
                              Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts
                                -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts"; bundle-version="1.8.400.v20191217-1710"; version="1.7.0"
                                   org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts [95]
                                     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.event; version="1.3.0"
                                       -> Export-Package: org.osgi.service.event; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.osgi.services"; bundle-version="3.8.0.v20190206-2147"; version="1.4.0"; uses:="org.osgi.framework"
                                          org.eclipse.osgi.services [262]
                                            Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.osgi.util.function; version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
                              Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log
                                -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.services"; bundle-version="2.2.200.v20200127-0814"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.services,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,  org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                                   org.eclipse.e4.core.services [107]
                                     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.event; resolution:="optional"
                                       -> Export-Package: org.osgi.service.event; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.osgi.services"; bundle-version="3.8.0.v20190206-2147"; version="1.4.0"; uses:="org.osgi.framework"
                                     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts
                                       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts; bundle-version="1.8.400.v20191217-1710"
                                     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.component.annotations; version="1.2.0"; resolution:="optional"
                                       -> Export-Package: org.osgi.service.component.annotations; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.osgi.services"; bundle-version="3.8.0.v20190206-2147"; version="1.3.0"
                                     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.log; version="1.3.0"
                                       -> Export-Package: org.osgi.service.log; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.osgi.services"; bundle-version="3.8.0.v20190206-2147"; version="1.4.0"; uses:="org.osgi.framework"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons
                         -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench"; bundle-version="1.11.200.v20200205-1503"; version="0.0.0"; x-internal:="true"
                            org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench [137]
                              Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.event; version="1.3.0"
                                -> Export-Package: org.osgi.service.event; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.osgi.services"; bundle-version="3.8.0.v20190206-2147"; version="1.4.0"; uses:="org.osgi.framework"
                              Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.component.annotations; version="1.2.0"; resolution:="optional"
                                -> Export-Package: org.osgi.service.component.annotations; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.osgi.services"; bundle-version="3.8.0.v20190206-2147"; version="1.3.0"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal
                         -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"; bundle-version="0.12.900.v20200110-1732"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench
                         -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench"; bundle-version="1.11.200.v20200205-1503"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.fragment,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,  org.eclipse.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.ui.ide.application,  org.eclipse.ui.ide,  org.eclipse.e4.emf.xpath.test"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.help.base; bundle-version="[4.0.0,5.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.help.base; bundle-version="4.2.902.v20210603-0901"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.help.base [220]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.lucene.analyzers-smartcn; bundle-version="[8.4.1,9.0.0)"
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty; resolution:="optional"
                  -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty"; bundle-version="3.7.400.v20210325-0520"; version="1.5.0"
                     org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty [177]
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet; version="[9.4.0,10.0.0)"
                         -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet"; bundle-version="9.4.48.v20220622"; version="9.4.48"; uses:="javax.servlet,javax.servlet.descriptor,javax.servlet.http,org.eclipse.jetty.http.pathmap,org.eclipse.jetty.security,org.eclipse.jetty.server,org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler,org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip,org.eclipse.jetty.server.session,org.eclipse.jetty.util,org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation,org.eclipse.jetty.util.component,org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource"
                            org.eclipse.jetty.servlet [246]
                              Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.jmx; version="[9.4.48,10.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
                              Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.util.ajax; version="[9.4.48,10.0.0)"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet; version="[1.2.0,2.0.0)"
                         -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet"; bundle-version="1.6.401.v20210322-1703"; version="1.2.0"
                            org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet [183]
                              Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.commons.fileupload; version="[1.2.2,2.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
                              Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk; version="[1.2.2,2.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
                              Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet; version="[1.2.2,2.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
                              Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.http; version="[1.2.0,1.3.0)"
                                -> Export-Package: org.osgi.service.http; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.osgi.services"; bundle-version="3.8.0.v20190206-2147"; version="1.2.1"; uses:="javax.servlet,javax.servlet.http"
```

Comment: Well it looks like your build has left out a lot of things, with no details about how you are building it is hard to say any more. The list of plug-ins required will have changed between 4.6 and 4.15 are you sure you have updated the list? Note that [tag:tycho] with maven is the recommended way to build RCPs.

Comment: Also did you update the product "start levels" to start `org.apache.felix.scr` which replaced `org.eclipse.equinox.ds`

Comment: I could able to resolve the issue after using org.apache.felix.scr. But now getting error Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini). I am using .product file to launch Eclipse RCP application

Comment: RCP build problems are extremely difficult to diagnose remotely, and impossible when you don't provide any information. At a complete guess your start levels is still wrong - click on the "Add Recommended" button in the Configuration/Start Levels section of the .product file editor.

Comment: org.apache.felix.scr@2\:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@2\:start,org.eclipse.equinox.common@2\:start,org.eclipse.equinox.event@2\:start,org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator@2\:start

Comment: config.ini file content:                                                                                                                              osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.15.200.v20200214-1600.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
eclipse.buildId=4.15.0.I20200420-1602
#osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2\:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3\:start,org.eclipse.equinox.ds@2\:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@start
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator@2\:start

Comment: Error message:!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:81)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)

Comment: That config.ini doesn't look much like what Eclipse/Tycho generates for me. You should try with "generate a default config.ini" specified and the recommended start levels.

Comment: Also use the [edit] button to add additional information to the question, not unreadable comments.